# Set Login History Application in External .NET Application

Tags: soap-api, c#, .net

Is it possible to set the application in the Login History object when logging in from a external .NET Application?

[image]

As you can see the application gets set to Browser when its a browser login, would it be possible to set this value when logging in through the *SForceService.login()* method?

Instead of it getting set to N/A I would like to populate this field with an application name ex:  *Salesforce SOAP API Tester*

Answer (score 0):

When using the Partner API you can set the [CallOptions.client](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#calloptions_client) header to a string before logging in.

Usually the value for this header is provided by Salesforce after passing the security review. Setting this header also allows you to access Professional edition orgs.

For the REST API, you can use a Connected App name to set the application column value.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  The documentation mentions that this is only available for the Partner API, is there an equivalent when using the Enterprise WSDL?

Comment: @LucasAnderson I wouldn't expect the Enterprise WSDL to have the same header as the Partner API. The intention is to identify external app exchange products that are connecting to your org. The Enterprise WSDL would never be used in this way with it being specific to the org it was generated from.